# choosing backgroung image for a textbox during runtime using c#, asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In a webform iam have placed one textbox, i want to choose a background image for that particular textbox during runtime. need coding in C#, ASP .NET

Answer (score 0):

You could use css to set the background image and javascript to change it. Here's an example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ToDDDD._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    input 
    {
        background-image: url(/initialImage.png)
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeImage() {
            document.getElementById('txt').style.backgroundImage = 'url(/newImage.png)';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" />
        <a href="#" onclick="changeImage();">Change background image</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited number of images that you want to use for the background then it would probably be cleanest to define each of them as a separate class in you css and then programatically either with javascript or C# change the class on the input.

> ```
> <style>  
>  .image1 { background-image: url(/image1.png);}
>  .image2 { background-image: url(/image2.png);}
>  .image3 { background-image: url(/image3.png);}
> </style>
> ```

In you Page_Load of you page you can then write this:

> txtBox1.CssClass = "image1";

Or using javascript:

> document.getElementById('<%=txtBox1.ClientID%>').setAttribute("class", "image2");